# Rails: DockerFile for Ruby failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to containerize my Ruby on Rails application. My dockerfile is written as below

```
FROM ruby:latest

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs yarn

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN gem install bundler:1.17.2
ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME
RUN yarn install --check-files
CMD ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0"]
```

However, my application is throwing an error below. What am I doing wrong here? I have also attached my gem file as below. PS sorry im a noob in rails and ruby and still learning on this :)

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (~> 4.0.0.beta2) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Your Ruby version is 2.7.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.1
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 18
```

My gem file as below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
#gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.5.0'
gem "bootstrap_form", "~> 4.0"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables'


# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
  gem 'byebug'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of your Gemfile in this question, so that we can see the gems that you listed in it?

Comment: If you need that exact version of Ruby, you can change your Dockerfile to build `FROM ruby:2.6.1` instead of `latest`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, from your Gemfile I can see that you defined the `rspec-rails` and the `byebug` gems twice.

Simply remove the `rspec-rails` and the `byebug` gems from the **development** group in your `Gemfile`, since you want them to be available in your **test** environment.

So your **development** group in your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Secondly, from your `Gemfile` you are using `Ruby 2.6.1` and `Rails 6.0.3`, but your Dockerfile is using the latest version of Ruby.

Modify your Dockerfile base image to have `FROM ruby:2.6.1` and not FROM `ruby:latest` since `Ruby 2.6.1` is not the latest version of Ruby.

Thirdly, you're running `Bundler:1.17.2` which might not work too well with Rails 6. Modify your Dockerfile to use `RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4`, and not `RUN gem install bundler:1.17.2`

You may also need to look at the most recent way of setting up `Ruby 2.6`, `Rails 6`, and `Bootstrap 4` in `Docker`.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**